# XML Structure to MySQL Table Structure

Tags: mysql, xml

how to make a good MySQL Database Table Structure from this XML-Code?

```
<xml>
<product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Test 1</name>
    <description>
        <weight>120t</weight>
        <height>20cm</height>
    </description>
</product>
<product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Test 1</name>
    <description>
        <length>100m</length>
        <strength>99%</strength>
    </description>
</product>    </xml>
```

How to solve the description entries?
I'm not able to know how many and which description information is given total.

**In my opinion:**

Table products: id, name

Table description: id, pid (ProductID), label, value

What do you think about this? Or what would be best?

Thanks for help.
TIA,
Frgtv10

----- EDIT

How to solve something like this at its best way?

```
<product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Test1</name>
    <description>
        <width>100</width>
        <price>
            <euro>
                <catalog>100</catalog>
                <online>98</online>
            </euro>
        </price>
    </description>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure looks good, personally I would drop the 'id' field of the 'description' table and rather use 'ProductId' + 'label' as the (now compound) primary key. But that's just me and it limits your table to only have unique labels for each product.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I edited the question above with a new "feature". How would it best to solve this? TIA!

Comment: This is exactly where manual mapping of deeply nested XML becomes painful, we could always keep on adding tables for each type of subelement, but in the end you should rather look at XML->Object marshaling frameworks like JAXP: http://jaxp.java.net/